# Multiple switchmap, should I unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here an example:

Is this approach correct?
Should I **unsubscribe** in each **switchMap**? Should I call **takeUntil** after each **switchMap**?

```
this.sharedSrv.postDetail.pipe(
  switchMap(post => {
    if (post) {
      this.hasPost = true;
      this.post = post;
    }

    this.viewedMainComment = null;
    this.viewedSubComments = [];
    return this.userSrv.getUserAsObservable();
  }),
  takeUntil(this.destroyFirstSwitchMap$), 
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      if (this.post.user.id == user.id) this.isOwnPost = true;
      this.user = user;
      console.log(user);
      return this.postsSrv.getPostInteraction(this.user.id, this.post.id, this.post.user.id);
    }
    return of(null); 
  }),
  takeUntil(this.destroySecondSwitchMap$),
).subscribe( );
```

Comment: One `takeUntil` as the last operator will suffice (I'm 90% certain of this!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one takeUntil will end all subscriptions in cascade.